# Copy All row (range) from one workbook to new excel - But first deleting duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

Im eliminating the duplicates, that not give any error.
Then i try to select all the row (not the same each time)
giving a error out of range

`MyBook.Sheets("Excel").Range("C1:P1000000").Copy .Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1")`

```
Dim rg As Range
    Dim rg2 As Range
    Set rg = Range("F2").CurrentRegion
    rg.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
       
    Dim MyBook As Workbook, newBook As Workbook
    Dim FileNm As String

    Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook

    FileNm = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "TEST-BOOK.xls"
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    With newBook
        MyBook.Sheets("Excel").Range("C1:P1000000").Copy .Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1")

        'Save new wb with XLS extension
        .SaveAs Filename:=FileNm, FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False

        .Close Savechanges:=False
    End With
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
dim newWb as workbook

activesheet.cells.copy
set newWb = workbooks.add
newWb .worksheets(1).cells(1,1).pastespecial
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.